# using variables in place of id names in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, append, mako

I desire to use a variable `i` that is incremented in a for loop to create unique id's in div's in a mako template.

```
var i=0;
    % for p in row.photos: 
    %if not p.PRIVATE:              
    /* setup div's for photo containers*/

    $('#photos').append("<div id='+i+' class='thumbnailimage'></div>"); 
    $('#+i+').append("<div id='+i+container' class='thumb_container'></div>");  
    $('#+i+container').append("<div id='+i+thumb' class='large_thumb'></div>");
    $('#+i+thumb').append("<div class='large_thumb_border'></div>");
    $('#+i+thumb').append("<div class='large_thumb_shine'></div>");

    /*insert the image*/
    $(document.createElement("img")).attr({ "src": "${tg.url('photo/%s/%s' % (p.PHOTOINDEX))}" }).appendTo('#+i+'thumb'');

    i++;


    %endif
% endfor
```

Result hoping for in the html when the javascript is run:

```
<div id='photos'>
    <div id='1'class='thumbnailimage'>
        <div id='1container' class='thumb_container'>
```

etc.
Instead I get:

```
<div id='photos'>
    <div id='+1+' class...>
    </div>
</div><!--end photos-->
```

Any suggestions?

Following the suggestions below, I changed the code to

```
$('#photos').append("<div id="'photo'+i+" class='thumbnailimage'></div>"); 
$("#'photo'+i+").append("<div id="'container'+i+" class='thumb_container'></div>");  
$("#'container'+i+").append("<div id="'thumb'+i+" class='large_thumb'></div>");
$("#'thumb'+i+").append("<div class='large_thumb_border'></div>");
$("#'thumb'+i+").append("<div class='large_thumb_shine'></div>");
```

Now I get an error message:
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
[Break On This Error]

```
$('#photos').append("<div id="photo+i+" class='thumbnailimage'></div>");
```

with arrow on the p in photo

FINALLY!!
I ended up having to define the whole variable outside of the jQuery command as it kept having problems with the + sign in the jquery href.  I used the following code to obtain the desired results.

```
    var i=0;

    % for p in row.photos:
     var photo='photo'+i;
     var photoId="#"+photo;
     var container='container'+i;
     var containerId="#"+container;
     var thumb='thumb'+i;
     var thumbId="#"+thumb;
       $('#photos').append("<div id="+photo+" class='thumbnailimage'></div>"); 
       $(photoId).append("<div id="+container+" class='thumb_container'></div>");  
       $(containerId).append("<div id="+thumb+" class='large_thumb'></div>");
       $(thumbId).append("<div class='large_thumb_border'></div>");   
       $(thumbId).append("<div class='large_thumb_shine'></div>");
       $(document.createElement("img")).attr({ "src": "${tg.url('photo/%s/%s' % (row.GISNUM, p.PHOTOINDEX))}" }).prependTo(thumbId);
% endfor
```

Comment: I have also tried the following format: id='(+i+)', id='(+i+'container')'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#photos').append("<div id='+i+' class='thumbnailimage'></div>");
```

to:

```
$('#photos').append("<div id='"+i+"' class='thumbnailimage'></div>");
```

Please note that if the doctype of the page is not HTML5, IDs must begin with a letter.

---

```
$('#photos').append("<div id='"+i+"' class='thumbnailimage'></div>"); 
$('#'+i).append("<div id='"+i+"container' class='thumb_container'></div>");  
$('#'+i+'container').append("<div id='"+i+"thumb' class='large_thumb'></div>");
$('#'+i+'thumb').append("<div class='large_thumb_border'></div>");
$('#'+i+'thumb').append("<div class='large_thumb_shine'></div>");
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that IDs must begin with a letter, although I would recommend that in general. Here is a [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/1405830) that covers some of the details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This works on the first div, but on the second div...I get an error: yntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Break On This Error]  

$("#+i+").append("<div id="+i+'container'" class='thumb_container'></div>");

Comment: @user1516104 You should change all the quotation marks where there is a `i` variable, for example `$("#+i+")` should be `$("#"+i).something()`

Comment: It looks like when I add double quotes with single quotes inside for the id="'something'+i" that the function sees the double quote as the closing quote for the function. See the new example I gave above...